# Derivative and logarithm of Dyson series

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, time-evolution

With  \begin{align}
{\cal T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right] 
&=
I - \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{0}^{t} dt' H(t')   + \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^2 \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{T}\left(\int_{0}^{t} dt' H(t')\right)^2
\\& \quad +
\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^3 \mathcal{T}\left(\frac{1}{3!}\left(\int_{0}^{t} dt' H(t')\right)^3\right) \cdots
\\ & =
I - \frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{t}dt' H(t') + \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^2 \int_{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t'}dt'' H(t') H(t'')
\\ & \quad
+ \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^3 \int_{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t'}dt'' \int_{0}^{t''}dt''' H(t') H(t'') H(t''') +\cdots
\end{align}

1. Is the derivative: $\frac{d}{dt} {\cal T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right]  = -\frac{i}{\hbar}H(t){\cal T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right]$
   I have a hard time seeing this from the expansion form above.
2. Is the logarithmic: $\ln {\cal T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right]  = -\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'$, where the time ordering disappear by taking logarithm?
3. Even if 2 is not true, will

   $\frac{d}{dt}\ln {\cal T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^tH(t')dt'\right] = -\frac{i}{\hbar}H(t)$

   be true?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes indeed, have you tried simply differentiating the series with respect to $t$? If you have, please describe in details where you got stuck.
2. No, that would hold for an ordinary exponent, but doesn't hold for the time-ordered one. Why would you think that the time-ordering disappears?

Comment: 1. I get stuck in $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t'}dt'' H(t') H(t'') = H(t)\int_{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t'}dt'' H(t') H(t'')$. I do not know the argument to say so and ignore $t'$.

Comment: 2. If it is not true, will it result in complicated expression?

Comment: @diff 1. What you wrote isn't correct. The $n$-th term in the Dyson series gives a $(n-1)$-th term in the resulting series after differentiation. In other words, the derivative always cancels one of the integrals.  2. Yes it will.

Comment: Since it will result in complicated expression in ln, I have added my question 3 and wonder if it is true.

Comment: @diff also not true. There's a unique solution to the 1-st order differential equation, which is given by the integral. In point 2 we see that the logarithm is not actually an integral.

Comment: The answer below says that taking logarithm will kill the time-ordering. Is that true? I think since after taking logarithm their is no product in the taylor expansion anymore, there is no need for time-ordering?

Comment: @diff First, please show me your definition of the logarithm of a linear operator.